# C# altering SQL table

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code:

```
try
{
    OpenDatabaseConnection();
    sql += @"ALTER TABLE @TableName " +
            "ADD @ColumnName @DataType(@Size)";

    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tableName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = columnName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@DataType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataType;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = size;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    CloseDatabaseConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     ArrowMessageBoxes.ArrowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
     CloseDatabaseConnection();
}
```

and when this code runs, I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near '@TableName'.

There must be something I am missing.

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically alter tables? If you need to update a table's schema, something like an SSDT project may be what you're after.

Needing to change your database schema on-the-fly for the proper operation of an application is a huge red flag. It means that your database is not properly designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDL can't contain parameters. If you insist on creating/altering tables and columns dynamically, you'll need to create dynamic SQL and [escape very, very carefully](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

Comment: This works fine when I create tables and when I insert into those tables. But the moment I alter the table......????

Comment: @Bebbie7 Are you parameterizing the table name for the create table?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this, but just the insert into and create tables. I'm allowing the users to create their own tables and stuff.

Comment: @Bebbie7 as this reply correctly states: that *cannot* be parameterized

Comment: You could create a proc called something like "AlterSchema" with all those parameters. then build and execute the dynamic sql with the param values. This will help with checking if the schema change is not a repeat (since you can look at sysobjects) and if the values are valid. My own opinion: this seems like a bad idea, what if you have a lock on the object while you change it? What if two calls/sessions attempt to make a change simultaneously?

Comment: @mrtig Agreed, although you can [obtain a lock](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) in the stored proc so only one change can be processed at a time.

Answer (score -1):

```
sql += @"ALTER TABLE [" + tableName + "] " +
        "ADD [" + columnName + "] " + dataType + " (" + size + ")";
```

Comment: As I said in my answer below, be careful. Consider something like `tableName = "foo] DROP [id]\nGO\nALTER TABLE [foo"`. Now that wouldn't be very good for business and that's the least of the kind of damage they could do